# Link or button to clear the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to figure out how to allow a user to click on a link or button on the index page to clear out all of the objects from the app's database, and then redirect to a newly cleared index page. So, with the example model `Article`, I expect it should have something to do with an `Article.destroy_all` method, and I'm expecting it would be a simple solution, but I've tried some variations and am just not sure of how to actually implement it.

Comment: In the `index` method of the controller in question, you'd do just as you say: run `destroy_all` on the objects you want to destroy, then do a `redirect` to wherever you want to go. Take a shot at it and if you get stuck come back to stackoverflow with a specific question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to destroy the objects every time the index action is called, only if the user opts to do so via a link or button on that page - so I'm not sure of how you mean to set this into place.

Comment: Of course, I was speaking generally. You could have an action within the context of that controller that triggers the destory, then does the `redirect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it would be another action in your controller. If we're dealing with Articles then the controller would be:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def indef
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def destroy_them_all
    Article.destroy_all
    redirect_to articles_path
  end
end
```

And in the view where you want the user to click on a button to destroy all articles:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy them all', destroy_them_all_path, method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you crazy?' %>
```

Don't forget to add a named route in your routes file:

```
match '/articles/destroy_them_all', to: 'Articles#destroy_them_all', via: :delete
```

That should work. Though you might have to check `rake routes` to make sure I got the `destroy_them_all_path` correct.

Comment: Much thanks! I got this to work with your suggestions, with a few necessary alterations. First, I changed the regular `destroy` method in my controller to have `Article.destroy_all` followed by `redirect_to articles_path`, and then removed the redirect from the `destroy_them_all` method above. Then, I changed the view's link to `articles_destroy_them_all_path`. Lastly, I changed the capitalized `Articles` in the named route above to a lowercase `articles`. (And there was also a typo in the `index` method above.) Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Article controller:

```
  def destroy_all
    @Articles = Article.all
    @Articles.each do |a|    
        a.destroy      
    end
    redirect_to articless_path, notice: "Delted"
  end
```

routes:

```
post "articles/destroy_all"
```

view:

```
<%= form_tag ({ :controller => 'articles', :action => 'destroy_all' }) do%>
 <%= submit_tag 'destroy all'%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That way of deleting records is slow and not recommended. You should use `Article.destroy_all` or its more efficient cousin - which doesn't run destroy callbacks: `Article.delete_all`.